# Formatting MMSS in SAS

Tags: sas

```
DATA USCFootballStatsProject;
INPUT OPPONENT $ 1-12 WINORLOSS 13-14 TIMEOFPOSSESSION 15-19 THIRDDOWNCONVERSIONPERCENTAGE 21-26 RUSHINGYARDS;
FORMAT TIMEOFPOSSESSION MMSS.;
CARDS;
UCF         1 24:30 0.125 32
GEORGIA     0 26:59 0.333 43
ALABAMA     0 22:53 0.333 71
TROY        1 31:47 0.333 116
AUBURN      0 28:51 0.167 70
KENTUCKY    1 29:11 0.636 139
VANDERBILT  1 24:50 0.333 132
TENNESSEE   1 32:08 0.353 65
ARKANSAS    1 27:53 0.429 45
FLORIDA     1 25:50 0.300 120
CLEMSON     0 28:12 0.250 167
MISSOURI    0 31:19 0.316 142
MISSSTATE   1 32:39 0.231 81
GEORGIA     0 29:08 0.364 35
WOFFORD     1 24:21 0.417 165
FLOATLANTIC 1 32:39 0.429 200
AUBURN      0 30:20 0.462 109
KENTUCKY    1 31:07 0.538 190
VANDERBILT  1 30:54 0.727 194
TENNESSEE   0 31:33 0.417 165
ARKANSAS    0 23:06 0.333 51
FLORIDA     0 30:31 0.500 135
MTENNESSEE  1 28:17 0.778 154
CLEMSON     1 32:57 0.600 208
HOUSTON     1 33:19 0.500 189
LOUISLFY    1 31:38 0.538 195
GEORGIA     1 30:34 0.091 140
SCSTATE     1 26:53 0.364 223
LSU         0 27:09 0.500 17
MISSSTATE   1 29:39 0.500 123
KENTUCKY    1 29:57 0.462 86
NCAROLINA   1 25:56 0.083 110
VANDERBILT  0 26:36 0.083 26
TENNESSEE   0 36:25 0.438 39
ARKANSAS    0 30:55 0.400 125
FLORIDA     0 25:39 0.167 68
CLEMSON     0 21:23 0.375 80
NCSTATE     1 34:15 0.357 171
VANDERBILT  0 29:58 0.400 92
GEORGIA     0 24:47 0.417 18 
WOFFORD     1 31:07 0.636 172
UAB         1 34:59 0.500 158
OLEMISS     1 31:21 0.538 78
KENTUCKY    1 30:43 0.471 74
LSU         0 25:28 0.111 39
TENNESSEE   1 32:30 0.500 101
ARKANSAS    1 29:06 0.417 132
FLORIDA     0 29:50 0.067 53
CLEMSON     0 27:13 0.471 92
IOWA        0 24:06 0.455 43
NCSTATE     1 32:25 0.333 108
GEORGIA     0 34:21 0.353 114
FLOATLANTIC 1 27:50 0.300 287
OLEMISS     1 33:35 0.375 65
SCSTATE     1 27:13 0.538 213
KENTUCKY    1 29:17 0.500 128
ALABAMA     0 31:43 0.474 64
VANDERBILT  1 32:22 0.375 119
TENNESSEE   0 26:35 0.267 65
ARKANSAS    0 27:37 0.500 53
FLORIDA     0 31:21 0.250 61
CLEMSON     1 36:31 0.375 223
CONN        0 24:32 0.200 76
SOUTHERMISS 1 28:52 0.400 224
GEORGIA     1 35:15 0.643 189
FURMAN      1 33:30 0.600 182
AUBURN      0 28:52 0.500 79
ALABAMA     1 27:33 0.545 110
KENTUCKY    0 25:13 0.500 90
VANDERBILT  1 37:21 0.529 129
TENNESSEE   1 28:28 0.538 212
ARKANSAS    0 25:40 0.417 105
FLORIDA     1 40:46 0.500 239
TROY        1 30:49 0.455 212
CLEMSON     1 34:43 0.333 95
AUBURN      0 28:59 0.417 156
FLORIDAST   0 26:32 0.500 139
ECU         1 30:02 0.500 220
GEORGIA     1 29:02 0.286 253
NAVY        1 31:15 0.556 254
VANDERBILT  1 34:08 0.526 131
AUBURN      0 24:13 0.200 129
KENTUCKY    1 38:37 0.500 288
MISSSTATE   1 32:34 0.200 110
TENNESSEE   1 36:18 0.556 231
ARKANSAS    0 29:05 0.667 79
FLORIDA     1 32:04 0.214 215
CITADEL     1 26:44 0.667 256
CLEMSON     1 37:17 0.444 210
NEBRASKA    1 29:11 0.308 121
VANDERBILT  1 31:36 0.250 205
ECU         1 28:42 0.533 131
UAB         1 23:47 0.500 179
MISSOURI    1 32:33 0.500 144
KENTUCKY    1 31:17 0.500 200
GEORGIA     1 33:13 0.417 230
LSU         0 23:03 0.231 34
FLORIDA     0 24:32 0.214 36
TENNESSEE   1 35:22 0.400 147
ARKANSAS    1 31:45 0.538 104
WOFFORD     1 29:11 0.538 171
CLEMSON     1 39:58 0.524 134
MICHIGAN    1 22:01 0.300 85
NCAROLINA   1 29:33 0.357 228
GEORGIA     0 24:58 0.455 226
VANDERBILT  1 37:10 0.647 220
UCF         1 30:49 0.556 225
KENTUCKY    1 29:45 0.556 178
ARKANSAS    1 43:25 0.563 277
TENNESSEE   0 27:38 0.286 218
MISSOURI    1 34:27 0.294 75
MISSSTATE   1 26:14 0.091 160
FLORIDA     1 28:59 0.313 164
CCAROLINA   1 34:31 0.556 352
CLEMSON     1 38:09 0.526 140
WISCONSIN   1 30:34 0.444 117
TAMU        0 22:22 0.222 67
ECU         1 36:19 0.538 175
GEORGIA     1 31:27 0.222 176
VANDERBILT  1 31:02 0.583 212
MISSOURI    0 35:55 0.381 119
KENTUCKY    0 34:20 0.600 282
FURMAN      1 29:37 0.333 267
AUBURN      0 33:31 0.429 119
TENNESSEE   0 30:13 0.462 248
FLORIDA     1 31:30 0.471 95
SALABAMA    1 24:12 0.400 210
CLEMSON     0 31:20 0.400 63
MIAMI       1 28:50 0.467 60
;
PROC PRINT DATA = USCFootballStatsProject;
RUN;
```

As it currently stands, it is not printing any of the times in the column for TIMEOFPOSSESSION, but it is printing everything else fine.  Any ideas as to why it isn't printing that column? I'm using FORMAT TIMEOFPOSSESSION MMSS.;

I plan on doing a logistic regression with the WINORLOSS being the response variable, but I want to make sure that the data is being read in correctly.

Thanks.

Comment: My code is showing up for me.  Are you not able to see it?

Comment: I would suggest you drop all the column ranges and use LIST input.  You can use the INFORMAT statement as suggested by Tom to read the TOP variable.  You are already using LIST input to read the last field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you told it to read columns 15 to 19 as a number, but the value has a colon in it. You need to either use formatted input.

```
input ... @15 TIMEOFPOSSESSION STIMER5. ... ;
```

Or use list mode input with an attached INFORMAT.

```
informat TIMEOFPOSSESSION stimer5.;
input ... @15 TIMEOFPOSSESSION ... ;
```

Comment: I really appreciate it.  I've been hung up on this for a bit.